# Unreasonable bottom space on the page

Tags: html, css, whitespace

Could someone please help me to figure out why does our website have big space at the bottom? 
Please see

http://www.zanadu.cn

I have been playing with it for some time already and couldn't figure out what the problem is.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
#main_content_container {
    top: -170px;
```

that's why

you should restructure your HTML to not need to shift the entire wrapper up 170px.

Comment: You could actually get the desired effect using `margin-top: -170px;` instead.

Comment: Thank you for noticing, I have actually found it few minutes after i posted this. unfortunately this page was not written by me, its complete mess from CSS view and I have to stick with it until new design comes. I have solved the issue by negative margin, which doesnt work in IE, but in IE I solved it with negative bottom margin. So solved, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

the question is why you have space. i got answer for that

In CSS #main_content_container has top -170px; and position: relative.

change that to

```
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
```

Comment: maybe only changing `top: -170px;` to `margin-top: -170px;`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using relative positioning. That only changes where the element is displayed, but it still takes up space in the original position.

So, you have used relative positioning to move the main container to overlap the menu, but the original position (where it would be without the relative positioning) is right at the bottom of the container.

Answer (score -1):

When you position something relatively, the space reserved for that element persists. So you move the div up, but space is still reserved for the initial state (before positioning)

one easy fix is to change the main_content_container top positioning to margin-top like so:

```
#main_content_container {
    margin-top: -170px;
}
```

This should make everything alright. Remember to remove the top: -170px rule here.

Comment: Didn't see it when I started writing the answer. Thanks a lot.